# Java resize combobox dropdown

Tags: java, swing, popup, jcombobox

I try to resize the dropdown of `combobox` and the code works since the third clicks :(.
The first click as the normal `combobox`, the `dropdown` has the same width.
Then the second time, the dropdown is larger but the scrollpane does not change.

[image]

I implemented the `popupmenulistener`, before the `dropdown` becomes visible,

```
public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent pme)
  {
    JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) pme.getSource();
    if (comboBox.getItemCount() == 0)
    {
      return;
    }
    final Object child = comboBox.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);
    if (child instanceof BasicComboPopup)
    {
      JList list = ((BasicComboPopup) child).getList();
      list.ensureIndexIsVisible(3);
      JScrollPane scrollPane = (JScrollPane) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JScrollPane.class, list);
      // int scrollBarWidth = 0;
      // if (comboBox.getItemCount() > comboBox.getMaximumRowCount()) {
      // JScrollBar vertical = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
      // scrollBarWidth = vertical.getPreferredSize().width;
      // }

      int popupWidth = 500;
      Dimension scrollPaneSize = scrollPane.getPreferredSize();
      scrollPane.getViewport().setSize(scrollPaneSize);
      // popupWidth = Math.max(popupWidth, scrollPaneSize.width);
      scrollPaneSize.width = popupWidth;
      scrollPane.setMinimumSize(scrollPaneSize);
      scrollPane.setPreferredSize(scrollPaneSize);
      scrollPane.setMaximumSize(scrollPaneSize);
      // scrollPane.repaint();

      // ((BasicComboPopup) child).setVisible(false);
      ((BasicComboPopup) child).setSize(scrollPaneSize);
      // ((BasicComboPopup) child).repaint();

      // comboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue("");
      // comboBox.setPrototypeDisplayValue(comboBox.getSelectedItem());

      // ((BasicComboPopup) child).revalidate();
      ((BasicComboPopup) child).setVisible(true);

    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you look at [this example](http://tutiez.com/how-make-jcombobox-drop-down-width-as-wide-as-needed.html) or [this example](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup/) or [this example](http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/make_jcombobox_popup_wide_enough)

Comment: thanks, i want to know why my code works since the 3rd click :) ?